# Very slow continued fraction convergence

Tags: nt.number-theory, limits-and-convergence, continued-fractions

Let $a(0)+b(0)/(a(1)+b(1)/(a(2)+b(2)/(a(3)+\dots)))$ be a continued fraction, and $p(n)/q(n)$ its $n$-th convergent. If it converges (i.e., $p(n)/q(n)$ tends to some limit
$S$ as $n\to\infty$), then $S-p(n)/q(n)$ can tend to $0$ in many different ways, for
instance superexponentially ($1/n!$, say), exponentially ($1/A^n$, say), subexponentially
($1/e^{C\sqrt{n}}$, say), polynomially ($1/n^k$, say). I noticed recently the apparently
well-known fact that it can also tend to $0$ logarithmically ($1/\log(n)$, say). My
precise question is as follows: assume for simplicity that $a(n)=1$ for all $n$, and that
$b(n)$ is a "sufficiently nice" function having asymptotic expansion as $n\to\infty$ of
the form $$b(n)=-\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{16n^2}+\dfrac{b_3}{n^3}+\dots$$
It is well-known that $-1/4$ is a crucial limit in the theory of CF, but here I also insist on the $-1/16$. Again, assuming $b(n)$ "nice", whatever that means, simply to avoid pathological examples, is it always true that the CF will converge (and in that case it will necessarily be in $1/\log(n)$), or does one need some extra information on $b_3$, etc... ?

Comment: I find the final question a little hard to understand. You seem to both allow extra conditions to avoid bad examples, but then also ask whether extra conditions are needed.

Comment: Edited I hope in a clearer manner.

Comment: Where cn one find this "well-known" result on $-1/4$?

Comment: In wanting to answer Alexey's comment, I found the answer to my question, which is not trivial. It is Theorem 32 page 159 of the book by Lorentzen and Waadeland "Continued fractions with applications" (1992), the result is too long to reproduce in a comment and involves products of iterated logarithms. In my special case it implies that the answer is YES, the CF always converges (and the $-1/16$ is of course crucial).

Comment: I must be confused about your notation. For a standard continued fraction (i.e. all $a(n)$ equal to 1 and all $b(n)$ positive integers), the convergence rate is always exponential. The slowest possible rate is for the golden ratio $\gamma$ (all $b(n)$ also equal to $1$), and that rate is like $\gamma^{-n}$.

This is easy to see since, for standard continued fractions, $|S - p(n)/q(n)| < 1/q(n)$, and the sequence $q(n)$ is generated by the recursion $q(n) = b(n) q(n-1) + a(n) q(n-2) \geq q(n-1) - q(n-2)$, so grows at least as fast as the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Oh wait, are you allowing non-integer $b(n)$??? I guess that would change things drastically, but then I would also definitely not call your original object a "continued fraction" but rather some sort of "generalized continued fraction"... (although even "generalized" only usually connotes that you're allowing $a(n) > 1$, not non-integer values.)

Comment: @RonniePavlov We have $b(n)=1$ for every $n$ for the standard continued fractions, so the situation is different here.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the OP's notation and exchanged $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ everywhere in my comment (usually I've seen them written with $a(n)$ in numerator). I still am curious about the entries: are the $b(n)$ indeed non-integer here?